# Checking the position in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

If I add a Pan Gesture Recognizer to the view and put down this code

```
recognizer.view.center.x > view.bounds.size.width
```

It is claimed that it can check whether it has passed half of the view yet.

What is the meaning of `recognizer.view.center.x`?

Answer (score 2):

`recognizer.view` returns the view that the pan gesture recognizer is attached to (the view which you added the recognizer to), and `recognizer.view.center.x` returns the x-axis value of the centre of the view (essentially half of the width).

As far as I can understand, `recognizer.view.center.x > view.bounds.size.width` will never be true because half of the width will never be larger than the width itself.

I assume you are trying to find whether if the point of touch has passed the middle of the view on the x-axis, try the following:

```
[recognizer locationInView:view].x > view.center.x
```

Similarly, if you want to find out if it has passed below the middle of the y-axis:

```
[recognizer locationInView:view].y > view.center.y
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the values.

1. `recognizer` is the pan gesture.
2. `view` is the view the recognizer has been assigned to.
3. `center` is the view's center point
4. `x` is the center's x coordinate.

All of this can be seen by reading the reference documentation for each class. `UIPanGestureRecognizer` extends `UIGestureRecognizer` which is where you will find details about the `view` property. Simply drill down from there.